# How to expose a dynamic array of records in DWScript?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

I've declared a simple record type in a DWScript unit:

```
TSampleRecord = record
  name: string;
end;
```

How can I expose such an array from the Delphi application to the script ?
For example, the following method in the Delphi application:

```
// Delphi side
function GetSampleRecordArray(): array of TSampleRecord;
```

Must be accessible from a script:

```
// Script side
var myArray: array of TSampleRecord;
myArray := GetSampleRecordArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before registering a function in script that returns dynamic array of records you need to:

1. register record type
2. register dynamic array of that type

`TdwsUnit` has helper method `ExposeRTTIDynamicArray` to expose dynamic arrays for scripting. The method is introduced by helper class `TdwsRTTIExposer` in unit `dwsRTTIExposer`. Unfortunately this works only with dynamic arrays of some basic types and not records or objects. Here's a simple class that helps you registering a record type and a dynamic array for the lifetime of `TdwsUnit` instance:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Rtti, dwsComp, dwsExprs, dwsInfo,
  dwsErrors, dwsRTTIExposer;

type
  TDwsDynamicArrayExposer<T: record> = class(TComponent)
  strict private
    FRttiType: TRttiType;
    FDwsSymbol: TdwsSymbol;
    FDwsArray: TdwsArray;
    function GetDwsUnit: TdwsUnit;
  strict protected
    class var RTTIContext: TRttiContext;
    property DwsUnit: TdwsUnit read GetDwsUnit;
    property RttiType: TRttiType read FRttiType;
    property DwsSymbol: TdwsSymbol read FDwsSymbol;
    property DwsArray: TdwsArray read FDwsArray;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SetInfo(const Info: IInfo; const Values: TArray<T>);
  end;

constructor TdwsDynamicArrayExposer<T>.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  if not (AOwner is TdwsUnit) then
    raise EArgumentException.Create('Owner must be instance of TdwsUnit.');
  inherited;
  FRttiType := RTTIContext.GetType(TypeInfo(T));
  FDwsSymbol := DwsUnit.ExposeRTTI(FRttiType.Handle);
  FDwsArray := DwsUnit.Arrays.Add;
  FDwsArray.DataType := FDwsSymbol.Name;
  FDwsArray.Name := FDwsSymbol.Name + 'Array';
  FDwsArray.IsDynamic := True;
end;

destructor TdwsDynamicArrayExposer<T>.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(DwsUnit) and (not (csDestroying in DwsUnit.ComponentState)) then
  begin
    // in case something went wrong in constructor
    FDwsArray.Free;
    FDwsSymbol.Free;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

function TdwsDynamicArrayExposer<T>.GetDwsUnit: TdwsUnit;
begin
  Result := TdwsUnit(Owner);
end;

procedure TdwsDynamicArrayExposer<T>.SetInfo(const Info: IInfo; const Values: TArray<T>);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Info.Member['Length'].ValueAsInteger := Length(Values);
  for Index := 0 to Length(Values) - 1 do
    TdwsRTTIInvoker.AssignRecordFromValue(Info.Element([Index]),
      TValue.From<T>(Values[Index]), RttiType);
end;
```

The class also provides conveniece method `SetInfo` for initializing `IInfo` instance (parameter, variable, result variable, ...) from a dynamic array.

Now you can define specialized exposer for your `TSampleRecord` and register function `GetSampleRecordArray` within the DWS unit:

```
type
  TSampleRecord = record
    Name: string;
  end;

  TArrayOfSampleRecordExposer = class(TdwsDynamicArrayExposer<TSampleRecord>)
  strict private
    FGetSampleRecordArrayFunction: TdwsFunction;
    procedure OnGetSampleRecordArrayEval(Info: TProgramInfo);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

function GetSampleRecordArray: TArray<TSampleRecord>;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 3);
  Result[0].Name := 'Name 0';
  Result[1].Name := 'Name 1';
  Result[2].Name := 'Name 2';
end;

constructor TArrayOfSampleRecordExposer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FGetSampleRecordArrayFunction := DwsUnit.Functions.Add;
  FGetSampleRecordArrayFunction.Name := 'GetSampleRecordArray';
  FGetSampleRecordArrayFunction.ResultType := DwsArray.Name;
  FGetSampleRecordArrayFunction.OnEval := OnGetSampleRecordArrayEval;
end;

destructor TArrayOfSampleRecordExposer.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(DwsUnit) and (not (csDestroying in DwsUnit.ComponentState)) then
    FGetSampleRecordArrayFunction.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TArrayOfSampleRecordExposer.OnGetSampleRecordArrayEval(Info: TProgramInfo);
begin
  SetInfo(Info.ResultVars, GetSampleRecordArray);
end;
```

Finally you register the Delphi function by instantiating `TArrayOfSampleRecordExposer`:

```
Dws := TDelphiWebScript.Create(nil);
DwsUnit := TdwsUnit.Create(Dws);
DwsUnit.UnitName := 'Unit1';
DwsUnit.Script := Dws;
// one-time registration
TArrayOfSampleRecordExposer.Create(DwsUnit);

// ...

DwsProgram := Dws.Compile(
  'var SampleRecords := GetSampleRecordArray;'#13#10 +
  'for var SampleRecord in SampleRecords do'#13#10 +
  '  Println(SampleRecord.Name);');
if DwsProgram.Msgs.Count > 0 then
  raise Exception.Create(DwsProgram.Msgs.AsInfo);
DwsProgramExecution := DwsProgram.Execute;
```

This should produce the output (`DwsProgramExecution.Result.ToString`):

> Name 0
>   Name 1
>   Name 2

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.